# How do I get python to read that () is 0?

Tags: python, parameters, variable-assignment

I'm having issues trying to pass an empty parameter can someone explain to me why my code isn't working. I have a math test file that goes through my math library file but my lib file can't read the () code. When I run the code it says **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

```
import MathLib as math
math test:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    math_obj1 = math.MyMathLib(2.0)
    math_obj2 = math.MyMathLib(-0.5)
    math_obj3 = math.MyMathLib() # this should give 0.0

    print("Math obj1 value = ",math_obj1.get_curr_value() )
    print("Math obj2 value = ",math_obj2.get_curr_value() )
    print("Math obj3 value = ",math_obj3.get_curr_value() )

import math
class MyMathLib:
    def __init__(self, y,):
        self.y = y
        if self == None:
            value == 0.0
```

Comment: Yes, becaue you've defined your `MyMathLib.__init__` to take `y` as a required positional argument, why did you think it would default to `0`? Note, `self == None` **will never be True** (well, not unless you manually pass `None` to `MyMathLib.__init__(None, None)` or something wacky like that...)

Comment: `def __init__(self, y=None):` or `def __init__(self, y=0.0):`. And you forgot `.y` in `if self.y is None: self.y = 0.0`

Answer (score 1):

The self variable isn't actually a passable parameter in class methods (I recommend you take another look at python [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)). The first (and only) passable parameter in your init function is `y`. Since `y` has no default variable, you **must** pass a value for `y`, or give it a default value:

```
def __init__(self, y=0.0):
    self.y = y
```

Also I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this line, it makes no sense:

```
if self == None:
    value == 0.0
```

`value` is only local to the init function, maybe you meant `self.value`? Even then, self will never be `None` (unless you assign `self = None` within the method), so the statement will never trigger. Ontop of that, you've used a double `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: oh i see i thought that self was the values in the () from the MathLib and y was the output variable thank you for the clarification

Comment: @Ryan can you please accept the answer that is best?

Answer (score 1):

As posted, your definition of the `__init__()` function has `y` as a *required* argument.

If you want it to be optional and have a default value of zero, then write it this way:

```
class MyMathLib:
    def __init__(self, y=0.0):
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `__init__` *requires* two arguments instead of one. Instead of doing this, you can pass a default variable like @Jay Mody's answer. And also:

`self == None` will never be true because `self` always passes in a value `y`.

Here is another way you can do it:

```
class MyMathLib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 0.0
    def passNumber(y):
        self.y = y
```

As you can see, if the number is passed using `passNumber`, that means that the number isn't `0.0`. This is another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default value in `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, y=0.0):
    self.y = y
```

and then you don't have to check `None`

Or using `None`

```
def __init__(self, y=None): 
    self.y = y
    if self.y is None:
       self.y = 0.0
```

It can be useful if you want to recognize if someone used `MyMathLib()` or `MyMathLib(0.0)`